# Xmonad key-binding on release

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmonad

I am trying to implement a keyboard layout switcher for xmonad as per [How do I change my keyboard layout while using xmonad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37491/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-layout-while-using-xmonad).

I want to use `Alt+LShift` since it is what I have used in years:

```
main = do
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
     {
        terminal = "gnome-terminal"
     } `additionalKeys`
     [ (( mod1Mask , xK_Shift_L), spawn "/home/gauthier/bin/layout_switch.sh")
     ]
```

My problem is that applications do not respond to shortcuts that contain `Alt+LShift` anymore. For example in emacs, I usually type `M-<` this way: `LAlt+LShift+.`.

With the layout switcher setup above, xmonad takes the key chord, and emacs gets nothing.

How can I keep the shortcut for keyboard switcher, and still have other applications take such shortcuts? I am ok with the keyboard switcher actually changing layout on release of `Alt+LShift`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to skip the script, and set the keyboard switch shortcut with `setxkbmap`.

I now run this in my login script:

```
# Keyboard layout switcher
setxkbmap -layout us,se -variant ,kinesis -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```

This does exactly what I wanted.